# Continuity of the union of two functions in a topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space with closed subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $X = A \cup B$. Let $f: A \rightarrow Y$ and $g: B \rightarrow Y$ be continuous functions such that for $x \in A \cap B$, $f(x)=g(x)$. Define a new function $f \cup g: X \rightarrow Y$ by

$f \cup g = \begin{cases} f(x), x \in A \\ g(x), x \in B \\ \end{cases}$

Prove that $f \cup g$ is continuous, and provide an example which shows why $A$ and $B$ must be closed.

This seems like a really obvious result, but I'm having a hard time providing a proof. For completeness's sake, the definition of continuity given is that a function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if for every open set $A$ in $Y$, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your "inverse image of open set is open" definition of continuous is equivalent to "the inverse image of a closed set is closed." By looking at continuity this way, we will see why $A,B$ being closed is important. Let $C \subset Y$ be closed. Now let's examine the inverse image of $C$ in $X, \space(f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$.

Let $x \in (f \cup g)^{-1}(C).$ Then $(f \cup g)(x) \in C$. However, $(f \cup g)^{-1}(C) \subseteq A \cup B$ so we also know $x \in A$ or $x\in B$. If $x \in A$ then $(f \cup g)(x)=f(x) \in C$ which implies $x \in f^{-1}(C)$. If $x \in B $ then $(f \cup g)(x)=g(x) \in C$ which implies $x \in g^{-1}(C)$. Thus for all $x \in \space(f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$ either $x \in g^{-1}(C)$ or $x \in f^{-1}(C)$, so $$(f \cup g)^{-1}(C) \subseteq f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C)$$ Now let $y \in  f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C)$. If $y \in  f^{-1}(C)$ then $y \in A$ because $f^{-1}(C) \subseteq A$. But if $y \in A$ then $f(y)=(f \cup g)(y) \in C$, which implies $y \in (f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$. Similarly, if $y \in  g^{-1}(C)$ then we will again find that $y \in (f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$. This means $$ f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C) \subseteq (f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$$ so we conclude $$ f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C)=(f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$$ Next let's consider the subspace $f(A)$. Since $C$ is closed in $Y$ we know $C \cap f(A)$ is closed in $f(A)$. Since $f$ is continuous we then know that $f^{-1}(C \cap f(A))=f^{-1}(C) \cap A$ is closed in the subspace $A$. By identical reasoning, $g^{-1}(C) \cap B$ is closed in the subspace $B$. Now we can use the immensely helpful fact that $A,B$ are closed in $X$ to note that sets are closed in a subspace iff they are closed in the space. We now know $g^{-1}(C) \cap B$ and $f^{-1}(C) \cap A$ are closed in $X$. The union of the two is also closed. Further, $$\left(g^{-1}(C) \cap B\right) \bigcup \left(f^{-1}(C) \cap A\right) = f^{-1}(C) \cup g^{-1}(C) = (f \cup g)^{-1}(C)$$ so the inverse image under $f \cup g$ of any closed set in $Y$ is closed in $X$ making $f \cup g$ continuous. $\Box$